# rails link_to - pass hash of values to controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

I have retrieved some records based on condition in a hash - `@special_products`. Now I want to pass the hash to a non-restful action(:special)/ of the same controller so that I can view the products.

I've tried this but how can link_to pass hash and how should the value be retrieved in `action: special?` which is in the same products_controller?Many thanks.

products_controller.rb

```
  def show
   @special_products = Product.by_company
  end
```

show.html.erb

```
<%= link_to "Special Products", special_path(:anchor => "#{@special_products}") %>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. If you're hitting the show action of the Products controller, you should be **showing a product**.
2. If you want to **show a product in a special way**, use the same `show` action, but render a different view for it.

   ```
   def show
     @product = Product.find(params[:id])
     render @product.special? ? 'special_show' : 'show'
   end
   ```
3. If you want to list some products in a different way (a filtered collection), you want to **use an index**. E.g. the `products#index` action.

   ```
   def index
     @products = Products.not_special
     @special_products = Products.way_special
   end

   # app/views/products/index.html.erb
   Special Products:
   <%= @special_products.pluck(:name).to_sentence %>
   ```
4. Finally, note that **the parameters you pass to `link_to` end up in the linked URL**, which means that your example `link_to` is going to render something like `#<Array []>` in the `href` attribute.

Comment: Considering point(2) even if I render special_show.html.erb, I still donot have the list of records in hash. basically, I'm viewing 1 product in show and there's a link below that says "View other products from this company" so even after rendering 'special-show' I have lost id of current product so as to display other products of that same company. I'm not sure if link_to can help. Now regarding point (3) @special_products contains all selected records so to_sentence will display comma-separated....not sure, if I'm understanding differently.

Comment: @Means I would have happily answered in a way that met your needs if you had explained what you were trying to do in your original question. You didn't, so I couldn't possibly have known. Please ask a new question.

Comment: I'm actually new to rails and apologies, I couldnot make it clear. Here's another question-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42656720/rails-link-to-pass-id-from-show-to-another-controller-action. thanks if you can give me some idea.