# Rails link_to pass :id from show to another controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

I'm viewing 1 product in show.html.erb and there's a link below that says "View other products from this company". This link_to connects to another non-restful action in same controller which retrieves from DB other products of same company as was shown in show.html.erb.

Can link_to pass the :id of the current product in show to action it's rendering? I'm new to rails and please let me know if question is not making sense. I'm not sure if routes need to be defined as well. Thanks.

products_controller.rb

```
def show
 @company_products = Product.by_company
end
```

show.html.erb

```
<%= link_to "View other products from this company", company_products_path(:anchor => "#{@company_products}") %>
```

routes.rb

```
get '/company_products_' => 'products#company_products'
```

Comment: Do you want the to have RESTFUL routes or keep the non-RESTFUL one you have?

Comment: I'm not sure how RESTFUL route will work.Kindly suggest

Comment: RESTFUL routes work as gwalshington suggest by typing in resources :products. What's confusing is that the name show.html.erb implies that you have restful routes (b/c Rails automatically fills that in as a potential URL/action when you add RESTFUL routes), when you don't have. You should find a tutorial explaining this, I really can't explain it in a comment properly . It's far too long and complicated.

Comment: I would suggest lynda.com's tutorial: https://www.lynda.com/Ruby-Rails-tutorials/Ruby-Rails-5-Essential-Training/500551-2.html?srchtrk=index%3a9%0alinktypeid%3a2%0aq%3aruby+on+rails+5%0apage%3a1%0as%3arelevance%0asa%3atrue%0aproducttypeid%3a2. You can use a different one if you want, but I'd start off with seeing how someone else builds their entire project first, then trying to build your own. It really is the quickest, and least frustrating way to learn Rails. Good luck! :)

Comment: Oh no, I know Restful routes! I've nearly finished an app all by myself:-) what I meant was I didnot understand how Restful route will work in 'my case' because you mentioned both restful and non-restful & I used non-restful.I only want to display few records(like an index) based on a condition.show is already displaying 1 record.how can I pass :id of current object from show to index or another non-restful action.What @gwalshington gave is for restful route.how will non-restful route be created?I guess link_to is not able to resolve route so it doesn't get displayed at all as she suggested.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, are you trying to link to show.html.erb or is this in the show.html.erb and you are trying to list another route. Also in the view you are putting the link in, are you in a single product's view (one that requires an id), or multiple? Also, you should post all your routes.rb, and the controller information for the view you are posting from to the view you are posting to (2 actions). Asking this b/c since you haven't used RESTFUL routing, I'm not sure what view corresponds to each action.

Comment: Sorry, for this confusion..actually I'm looking at 1 product in show...and using that :id going to display all products (hashcompany_products) of that company. I have specified hashcompany_products in show because I need to pass that hash as parameter of link_to to another non-restful action.. hope it clarifies.

Comment: Now, I think instead of passing hash better to pass only :id of object in show to non-restful action as it maybe easier with link_to....and then in that non-restful action using that :id find all products and then display. thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally resolved it by passing the :id of object in show via link_to to a non-restful action.

I'm open to suggestions if entire @company_products in #show can be passed as it is because I'm first finding if there are any other products for that company and if there are, passing an id only in link_to and in controller#company again running a query to get same data of all products to display. so running same query twice is not DRY.

controller#show remains the same as originally posted.

routes.rb

```
resources :products do
  get :company, on: :member
end
```

show.html.erb

```
<%= link_to "View other products from #{@company_name}", company_product_path(@product.company_id) %>
```

controller#company

```
def company
  @products_of_company = Product.where(company_id: params[:id])
end
```

Now in company.html.erb, the list is just displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You want to do something like this:

```
@company_products.each do |company|
  link_to "View other products from this company", products_path(company)
end
```

routes:

`resources :products`

Comment: What you have mentioned is index view. I'm asking for link_to in show.So in any case I have the current product. link_to by passing hash-product or product.id is not displaying at all. No errors also. Any suggestions.